# Access Control List in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to use Access control functionality in Fabric (like permission.acl in Hyperledger Composer), so how to achieve this in Fabric? and how to specify the user while accessing chaincode to test the Access controls provided for that user from node SDK.
eg:(like Tuna-network example in Composer) I want to give different CRUD access to chaincode functions to different participants/users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent in hyperledger fabric for the Composer ACL functionality.

First you should look at access control lists in fabric to ensure that your fabric network has the correct level of security 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/access_control.html
(You would have to have done this anyway as even if you used composer ACLs to ensure a participant could not read something, if that pariticpant had the ability to query the ledger or is able to listen for block events they could still infer the data, unless encrypted, regardless of the Composer ACL denying read access).

The other fabric capability you could look at is what's termed "Attribute Based Access Control". This is where attributes with values are associated with a certificate and the fabric shims for each language provide a utility library to allow chaincode to extract those attribute values and then the chaincode implementation can make a decision on whether the identity making the request has the appropriate authority to perform whatever it has requested.

More details can be found here
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/chaincode4ade.html?highlight=client%20identity#chaincode-api